# Вставки какого ассемблера поддерживает С/С++?

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

Какой из них? NASM? MASM? FASM? Все?

Comment: Поддерживает и зависит от того который использует ваш компилятор, в основном это nasm под gcc и masm в vc

Comment: @Arenoros, на самом деле и там и там свой синтаксис, в gcc используется GAS. В vc тоже ЕМНИП свой диалект.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, точно, забыл про gas, а вот с vc точно masm, https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/assembler/inline/asm?view=vs-2019